# Strange Clustered Key Lookup on a Filtered Index in SQL Server 2014 when using IS NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to use a filtered index to optimize a query for a very specific scenario. For simplicity I have managed to duplicate my problem with a dummy table Test. Here is my setup:

```
CREATE TABLE _Test
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Finished BIT NULL,
    Data INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( Id )
);


CREATE INDEX IX_Test_NotFinished ON _Test ( Data ) WHERE ( Finished IS NULL );
```

Using this as a source table the next query produces some very strange execution plan:

```
SELECT Data FROM _Test WITH ( INDEX( IX_Test_NotFinished ) ) WHERE Finished IS NULL;
```

Instead of seeing only a non clustered index scan, I am seeing a key lookup for the Finished field. Including the field in the index (e.g. `INCLUDE( Finished )` ) eliminates the key lookup, but it shouldn't be needed in the first place.

Note: If the finished field is non nullable and the filter expression was **Finished = 0**, then no key lookup occurs, but since my example is a simplification of the real database structure I have in hand, I need the filtered index to use IS NULL.

Comment: It looks exactly like: **[Filtered Indexes: Just Add Includes](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/12/filtered-indexes-just-add-includes/)**  [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415548?opt.withExecutionPlan=true#executionPlan)

Comment: @lad2025 the issue is nothing to do with statistics.

Comment: @MartinSmith That was quote from blog. [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/643850/filtered-index-execution-plan-is-not-optimized) explains it correctly.

Comment: @lad2025 Or this one https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/454744/filtered-index-not-used-and-key-lookup-with-no-output